# How to delete a large number of specified graphics in OpenGL with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I use OpenGL with Qt to draw millions of lines. There are some lines don't need to delete and other lines need to delete. So I put the pointer of lines which need to delete to a `QList`. When need to delete these lines, I delete pointer first, and then clear the `QList`. But I found the operation is time-consuming, especially in my embedded device. Some code like this:

```
class Drawable : protected QOpenGLExtraFunctions
{
......
}

class GlWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions_ES2
{
public:
void addNeedToDeleteDrawable(Drawable *drawable){
    need_to_delete_drawerlist.append(drawable);
    alldrawerlist.append(drawable);
}
void deleteDrawable()
{
    if(need_to_delete_drawerlist.isEmpty()) return;
    for(auto& p : need_to_delete_drawerlist){
        auto index = alldrawerlist.indexof(p);
        delete p;
        p = nullptr;
        alldrawerlist.removeAt(index);
    }
    need_to_delete_drawerlist.clear();
}
private:
QList<Drawable*> alldrawerlist;              //contains all lines to paint
QList<Drawable*> need_to_delete_drawerlist;  //contains lines need to delete
}
```

When I need to delete lines which need to delete, I call the funciton `deleteDrawable()`. This way spends a lot of time when `need_to_delete_drawerlist` contains millions of elements. Is there any other way to achieve this or how to optimize this function?

Comment: If memory is not a concern you can return these objects to a freelist instead of deleting them. And then of course take elements from the freelist instead of creating new ones.

Comment: Could you please tell me in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the memory budget for it, you can try to reuse Drawable objects instead of deleting them.
First, keep a (global) freelist:

```
QList<Drawable*> freelist;
```

Then, when you allocate a new Drawable, first see if there are any in the freelist:

```
Drawable *newDrawable() {
    if (freelist.isEmpty())
        return new Drawable;
    return freelist.takeFirst();
}
```

You can also create a variant of this function that directly performs the proper initialization:

```
template<typename... Args>
Drawable *newDrawable(Args&&... args) {
    if (freelist.isEmpty())
        return new Drawable(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto el = freelist.takeFirst();
    *el = Drawable(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return el;
}
```

Finally, when you intend to delete a Drawable, call `freelist.append(drawable)` instead.

Comment: The lines have different angle which is real time computing. So I think resue is impossible. But it's a good idea to solve my another question. Thank you!

Comment: Note that you're only reusing the object memory; you're supposed to change the drawable after you get it from new or the freelist. That's what the second form does automatically.

Comment: This method is effective. It worked well. Thank you very much for your answer @Botje.